# Finding the Integral using the Residue

Tags: complex-analysis

I found this problem in my university previous exam session and there was this exercise that i can't figure it out how to do and i was hoping for some help here if possible.

So the exercise goes like this:

Given $F(z)$ and $\gamma$ find the integral along the line $\gamma$

$F(z)=\frac {sin(z)}{z^2(z^2+9)}$  and $\gamma$=2cos(2t)+2isin(2t)

find $\int_{\gamma } f(z)dz$

Now i know that to do this i have to compute the residues and $\int_{\gamma } f(z)dz=2\pi i \sum_i(Res(f,z_i))$

First we have to find the singularities and they are $z_1=0 ,z_2=+3i,z=-3i$

Since $z_2=+3i,z=-3i$ are not included in $\gamma$ we don't consider them and we focus only on $z_1=0$

But i cant seem to understand where the problem lies!

What i know is that to compute the residue of a singularity z we do this :

$lim_{z \to 0 } \frac {sin(z)}{z^2 +9}=0$???

And i know that since  $\gamma=2cos(2t)+2isin(2t)$= $\gamma=2(cos(2t)+isin(2t))$ we take 2 times the $Res$ so $2\cdot 0=0????$

Here it says that the answer is $\frac 49\pi i$

So where is the mistake?

[image: Picture of the problem]

Comment: That contour passes *through* the singularity $z = 0$, so the residue theorem is not going to be your friend here. Have you drawn an actual graph of $\gamma$ to see how it looks and how it gets traced out as $t$ increases?

Comment: Is there a typo? Is $\gamma$ really a sort of back and forth line, or is it meant to have an $i$ in front of the sine term so that it forms a circle?

Comment: @KCd I haven't but we are supposed to use some formulas here. I just think i might be using the wrong one

Comment: @David yeah my bad i fixed it

Comment: After reading your correction, the curve $\gamma$ traces out a circle centered at $0$ of radius $2$, but what is the range of $t$ values?  Without telling us that, we have no idea how many times the circle is traced out.  Please give us the *complete* version of the exercise.

Comment: To find the residue, you have to figure out that $1/z$ term in $\sin(z)/(z^2(z^2+9))$. Since $\sin z$ has a simple zero at $z = 0$, the residue is  $\lim_{z \to 0} \sin(z)/(z(z^2+9))$. You lost a factor of $z$ in the denominator for some reason.

Comment: @KCd I added a picture of the full problem copy pasted from the source

Comment: Okay, then you should put the parameter range $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$ directly into the exercise that you wrote at the top.  Don't just rely on that information being part of the image: it's not recommended on this site to leave crucial information in an image if it can be typed directly into the post (which can be done in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualy $\gamma(\theta)$ is the circle $|z|=2$ but scrolled twice.

$f(z)$ have a pol of the order one $z_0=0$ and the poles $z_{1,2}=\pm3i$. Only $z_0$ is inside the circle so:

$$\int_{\gamma}f(z)=2\int_{|z|=2}f(z)=4\pi iRes(f(z),0)=4\pi i\lim_{z\rightarrow0}zf(z)=4\pi i\lim_{z\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin{z}}{z}\frac{1}{z^2+9}=\frac{4\pi i}{9}$$